# JS function only works properly after clicking on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a **title generator with HTML, CSS and JavaScript**. The following code is supposed to do this:

1. Enter Edit-Mode with pressing of the "Enter"-Key (works correctly)
2. Turning down the opacity of the top left and top right box by clicking on the red buttons (works)
3. Hiding both items when exiting Edit-Mode by pressing "Enter" again. (works)
4. Enter Edit-Mode again and showing both hidden div boxes with opacity set to 20% (**does not work**)

Only the first box that was clicked on shows up again. It seems like the class "deactivated" is not safed for the last item being clicked on as it disappears on step 3.

**However** it does work when I click somewhere on the document before going to step 3.

Any help appreciated!

**[Full version can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmt9wa1s/)**

```
/*Switch between Display and Edit Mode*/

function toggleHideUI() {
  var HideUI = document.getElementById("hiddenUI");
  if (HideUI.style.display === "block") {
    hideHiddenElements();
    HideUI.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    showHiddenElements();
    HideUI.style.display = "block";
  }
};

/* EventListener for "Enter" Keybind */

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code == "Enter") {
    toggleHideUI();
  }
});

/*Hide hidden elements (class = "deactivated") for Display Mode */

function hideHiddenElements() {
  var HiddenElements = document.getElementsByClassName("deactivated");
  for (i = 0; i < HiddenElements.length; i++) {
    HiddenElements.item(i).style.display = "none";
  }
};

/*Show hidden elements (class = "deactivated") for Edit Mode */

function showHiddenElements() {
  var HiddenElements = document.getElementsByClassName("deactivated");
  for (i = 0; i < HiddenElements.length; i++) {
    HiddenElements[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}


/*Toggle DB Logo in upper left corner*/

document.getElementById("hide-db-logo").onclick = function toggleDBLogo() {
  document.getElementById("db-box").classList.toggle("deactivated");
}

/*Toggle Campus Logo in upper right corner*/

document.getElementById("hide-campus-logo").onclick = function toggleCampusLogo() {
  document.getElementById("campus-box").classList.toggle("deactivated");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the working script as:

The problem is when you click enter when the element is in focus, the event is propagating back.

```
<script>
        /*Switch between Display and Edit Mode*/

        function toggleHideUI() {
            let HideUI = document.getElementById("hiddenUI");
            if (HideUI.style.display === "block") {
                hideHiddenElements();
                HideUI.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                showHiddenElements();
                HideUI.style.display = "block";
            }
        };

        /* EventListener for "Enter" Keybind */

        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            if (e.code == "Enter") {
                e.preventDefault(); //<--- notice here
                toggleHideUI();
            }
        });

        /*Hide hidden elements (class = "deactivated") for Display Mode */

        function hideHiddenElements() {
            let HiddenElements = document.getElementsByClassName("deactivated"); //<--- notice here use let instead of var
            for (let j = 0; j < HiddenElements.length; j++) {
                HiddenElements[j].style.display = "none";
            }
        };

        /*Show hidden elements (class = "deactivated") for Edit Mode */

        function showHiddenElements() {
            let HiddenElements = document.getElementsByClassName("deactivated");
//<--- notice here use let instead of var
            for (let i = 0; i < HiddenElements.length; i++) {
                HiddenElements[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        }


        /*Toggle DB Logo in upper left corner*/

        document.getElementById("hide-db-logo").onclick = function toggleDBLogo() {
            document.getElementById("db-box").classList.toggle("deactivated");
        }

        /*Toggle Campus Logo in upper right corner*/

        document.getElementById("hide-campus-logo").onclick = function toggleCampusLogo() {
            document.getElementById("campus-box").classList.toggle("deactivated");
        }

    </script>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: It has to be in focus, not hovered over!

Comment: Perfect this works!

Could you explain why you used let instead of var inside the functions? By propagating back you mean that it triggers the default function of "Enter" which is activating the hyperlink again, right?